# How do I add an existing IntelliJ Java project to git?

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea

This question is similar to [this one for Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25515393/how-do-i-add-existing-eclipse-java-project-to-git) but with a different IDE.

How can I add my pre-existing Java to git in IntelliJ IDEA?

**Current State:**

- Existing Spring Boot Project initialized from [start.spring.io](https://start.spring.io/)
- Newly created GitHub repository

I could check out the new repository, copy the contents of my project to this directory and just push to master, but is there a simpler way within the IDE that avoids changing the location of the project?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Go to `VCS > Import into Version Control > Create Git Repository`
2. Then go to `VCS > Git > Remotes`
3. Click the `+` button, leave origin as-is and paste the Git URL of your repository
4. `VCS > Git > Git Pull` then `VCS > Git > Git Push`

Comment: You might want to add an extra task in step 1, `VCS > Import into Version Control > Create Git Repository > Select current Project folder.` This is how it worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

'*VCS*' on the menu bar > '*Import into Version Control*' > '*Create Git repository...*'

---

To hopefully somewhat future-proof this answer in case the location moves, you can use:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> (or <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> on a Mac) to open the action search dialog and search for 'create git'.

Comment: I am using MAC-OS so i think the command will be <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>. Also i want to use enterprise github, will that also work with this.

Comment: Yeah. The specific details of the remote URL don't matter. Vinz's answer shows how to set up the remote URL.